# memory reading double value as cheat engine in c#

Tags: c#, memory, double

I'm not a pro in code writing and C# programming.
I wrote a simple app to read from process memory using the ZeraPain script ReadProcessMemory().
Is working good with the 4 bytes and 8 bytes value.
The other function of this App is that can read strings, but i really need to read Double values and i cant find anything on the web.
Can somebody HELP me with this?
here's a printscreen of the app
[image]

Here's the class (by ZERAPAIN)

```
class Memory
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(UInt32 dwDesiredAccess, Boolean bInheritHandle, UInt32 dwProcessId);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
    byte[] lpBuffer, UIntPtr nSize, uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    IntPtr Handle;

    public Memory(string sprocess)
    {
        try
        {
            Process[] Processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(sprocess);
            Process nProcess = Processes[0];
            Handle = OpenProcess(0x10, false, (uint)nProcess.Id);
        }
        catch
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }

    public string ReadString(uint pointer, Int32 bts)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[bts];

        ReadProcessMemory(Handle, (IntPtr)pointer, bytes, (UIntPtr)24, 0);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }

    public int ReadPointer(uint pointer, Int32 bts)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[bts];

        ReadProcessMemory(Handle, (IntPtr)pointer, bytes, (UIntPtr)sizeof(int), 0);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
    }
}
```

And here's the script

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Memory mem = new Memory(processnameTB.Text);
            uint address = Convert.ToUInt32(AddressTB.Text, 16);
            if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    int byt = Convert.ToInt32(bytesnumberTB.Text);
                    string str = mem.ReadString(address, byt);
                    stringvalue.Text = str;
                }
                catch
                {
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    int byt = Convert.ToInt32(bytesnumberTB.Text);
                    double pointer = mem.ReadPointer(address,byt);
                    pointervalue.Text = pointer.ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: what makes you think the print screen of your app would be of any use to anyone here? lol

Comment: ok ill post the code now...

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of bytes that represent the double, you can use BitConverter.ToDouble() to convert those bytes to a double

> The ToDouble method converts the bytes from index startIndex to startIndex + 7 to a Double value. The order of bytes in the array must reflect the endianness of the computer system's architecture; for more information, see the Remarks section of the BitConverter class topic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.todouble(v=vs.110).aspx